# Align vertically a pseudo-element

Tags: css, css-transforms

I'm trying to cross vertically the rotated square with a line created using pseudo-element.

```
.marker{
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: solid 2px #896f56;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.marker:before{
    content: "";
    width: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #896f56;
    display: block;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    margin-left: 19px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npvfu3ff/

But the rotate rule is affecting the pseudo element making it difficult to position.

Here is an image of what I need:

[image]

Comment: Do you want this all to be contained within a single element?  Would you be willing to place a square and a line inside of a container?  If not, you could use `position:absolute; top:-11px; left:8px;` make sure your main element has `position:relative;` on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the way to do it, so that it will center automatically

```css
.marker{
 display: block;
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 border: solid 2px #896f56;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
     margin-top: 30px;
}

.marker:before{
 content: "";
 width: 2px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #896f56;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50%;
    transform:rotate(-45deg) translatey(-50%);
    transform-origin: top center;
}
```

```html
<div class="marker"></div>
```

Comment: Please, see the image above.

Comment: Updated ... didn't understand your idea

Answer (score 0):

I detached marker line from rotation by using `:before` and `:after` for square and line, so they don't affect each other.

https://jsfiddle.net/wmqhd72u/

```
.maker2 {
    position: relative;
}
.maker2:hover:before {
    transform: rotate(405deg);
}
.maker2:before,
.maker2:after {
    position: absolute;
}
.maker2:before {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: solid 2px #896f56;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all 2s;
}
.maker2:after {
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    top: -8px;
    left: -8px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #896f56;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 19px;
    top: 8px;
    left: -10px;
}
```